# "TypeError: _this2.setState is not a function" React Native

Tags: react-native

For some reason I am getting the error "TypeError: _this2.setState is not a function"

in my code here:

```
import React, {useEffect, Component} from 'react';

import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

class HomePageContent extends Component {
  state = {
    uData: [],
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        var userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        const db = firebase.firestore();

        let userDB = db.collection('Users').doc(userID);
        userDB
          .get()
          .then(doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
              console.log('No such document!');
            } else {
              let allUsers = [];
              let data = doc.data();
              let currentUser = data.fName;
              allUsers.push({
                currentUser,
              });
              this.setState({uData: allUsers});
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting document', err);
          });
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        {this.state.uData.map((value, index) => (
          <Text style={{fontSize: 25}}>Welcome {value.currentUser}</Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default HomePageContent;
```

Basically I am just trying to set the state and then use it in

```
  <Text style={{fontSize: 25}}>Welcome {value.currentUser}</Text>
```

However I am getting the error for some reason. Any ideas why? I am doing it how I would typically do it in reactJS but this is react native.

The full error is this:

```
Error getting document [TypeError: _this2.setState is not a function. (In '_this2.setState({
                  uData: allUsers
                })', '_this2.setState' is undefined)]
```

Comment: Have you tried making the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {` method an arrow function? To something like `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {..`

Comment: @nipuna777 that fixed it lol! I don't get it, I just needed to use an arrow function? Why was that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the `this` context is not the one you are expecting.

When you create a callback method using the function syntax, you are createing a new scope for `this`. And when you call `this.setState` JS will be looking for a `setState` method inside the newly created function.

```
function(user) {
      ...
      // this refers to the functional context here
}
```

This can be fixed by using a arrow function.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {...}
```

The arrow function does not have its own binding to the `this` keyword. You can read a bit more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Since the function doesn't have a `this` context, it will automatically refer to the parents `this` which does have the `setState` method.

Another way to fix this would be to use a function and bind `this` manually using `.bind`.

Comment: Man thank you so much for taking the time to explain that for real! You are great!

Answer (score 0):

Using an arrow function at firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => { fixed this thanks @nipuna777